# What did Luiz Adriano do wrong in scoring a 'cheat goal'?

Tags: football

The news report on [this](http://au.eurosport.com/football/champions-league/2010-2011/shakhtar-s-luiz-adriano-charged-over-cheat-goal_sto3500507/story.shtml) site describes how Luiz Adriano scored an unsportsmanlike goal...

> Adriano...rounded the Danish club's keeper to score after an
>   uncontested drop-ball

...and will reportedly face disciplinary charges. I am not familiar with the finer points of the written and unwritten rules and etiquette that apply in the situation, [Article 5, UEFA Disciplinary Regulations](http://www.uefa.com/newsfiles/19066.pdf).

What was the situation that lead to this goal and what did he do wrong? What is a player supposed to do instead in this situation? Did he violate an explicit law or a gentlemanly convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The goal is totally valid, and I really doubt he will face any disciplinary charges. The play was stopped by the referee because a player was lying on the field after a challenge. To restart the match, the ref has to drop a ball (law 8 - dropped ball) to restart the match. Usually there is no rule about who will keep the ball, but implicit rules usually make the team that not have the ball, to give it to the opposite team, sending it out, or kicking it far in the other team field.

The ball was in fact kicked far to the opposite field, but Adriano run for it and made a goal. He just violated a gentleman convention.

Comment: He was banned for a single match.